# Find a list of words using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am going to find a match like below. Just explained using words.
ComanyCode + dot + [4 Digit Number]

Some Examples as follows
US.1234, UK.4321 etc

```
import re

txt = "TheUS.8888 in S8ain"
```

I am trying to use an array of input parameters.

Below is how I approached this. Can someone suggest me the correct way.

```
Companys = ['UK','CA','GE''US']  


for k in Companys:
    x = re.findall("k.\d\d\d\d", txt)
```

Ideally  from above sample code `US.8888` should be returned.

Comment: So basically you want to find an easy way to filter strings for certain patterns. Look into regular expressions. (Here is a start: https://regexr.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `re.findall` here with an alternation:

```py
txt = "TheUS.8888 in S8ain"
countries = ['UK', 'CA', 'GE', 'US']
regex = r'(?:' + '|'.join(countries) + r')\.\d{4}'
print(regex)    # (?:UK|CA|GE|US)\.\d{4}
matches = re.findall(regex, txt)
print(matches)  # ['US.8888']
```